# Convert gregorian date to persian date (jalali) in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, date

How can I convert a Gregorian date to a Persian date in Qt?

Comment: Voted to reopen as this question provably has a constructive answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update: Use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61604291/2632266).

[QDateConvertor](https://github.com/kharazi/qdateconvertor) class can help you to convert your date form geogorian to jalali and jalali to geogorian.

**Edit:**
Add this class to your project and include "qdateconvertor.h" where you need to convert date.

```
   // gregorian to jalali 
   QDateConvertor mdate;
   QStringList shamsi=  mdate.ToJalali( "2001","9","11");
   QString JalailDate =shamsi.at(0)+"/"+shamsi.at(1)+"/"+shamsi.at(2)+ ":" +shamsi.at(3);
   qDebug()<<JalailDate;    
   // jalali to gregorian
   QStringList m= mdate.ToMiladi("1372","3","6");
   QString miladiDate= m.at(0)+"/"+ m.at(1)+"/"+m.at(2);
   qDebug()<<miladiDate;
```

Comment: There is one single issue report on the suggested library, and it doesn't promise much good. It seems to be generating bad output in some cases, which is the last thing you'd want.

Answer (score 7):

For QT >= 5.14 you can do like this without any third-party dependencies:

```
QCalendar calendar(QCalendar::System::Jalali);

QDate today = QDate::currentDate();

QCalendar::YearMonthDay ymd = calendar.partsFromDate(today);

qDebug() << ymd.year;
qDebug() << ymd.month;
qDebug() << ymd.day;

qDebug() << QString("%1/%2/%3")
            .arg(ymd.year, 4, 10, QChar('0'))
            .arg(ymd.month, 2, 10, QChar('0'))
            .arg(ymd.day, 2, 10, QChar('0'));
```