# How to show current Date in different calendars in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I only want to show the current date as a string using something like `new Date().toLocaleString`. But I don't see any way to convert the date to the desired calendar (for example hijri/jalali calendar).
Also I don't want to use any extra c++ code, only QML types or something like a javascript function in my QML files.
Is there any way to do it? A sample code would be appreciated.

Comment: There is some C++ [extension](https://github.com/kharazi/qdateconvertor) that do what you want, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16005114/convert-gregorian-date-to-persian-date-jalali-in-qt) for example. Also [this](https://github.com/jalaali/jalaali-js) javascript library makes the same but again, it't kind of extra code, I don't think that you can do the same in pure QML but it's possible that I'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

Use `Qt.formatDate` for that. It accepts a format string or a named standard format.

Comment: That only specifies format, not the calendar.

Comment: Ah, sorry, overlooked that part of the question.